# Can't extract a zip file with jar -xf even after granting full permissions using icacls

Tags: java, batch-file, glassfish, unzip, icacls

First i had to suffer to make the icalcs grant full permissions to everyone in a folder as i didn't know that i should write "Tout le monde" instead of "everyone" as my windows 7 language is french and actually i needed this command for that i can unzip a zip file in the same permissions altered folder.

the code of my batch file is the following :

```
call xcopy glassfish-4.1.zip C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2
icacls C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2 /grant "Tout le monde":f
call C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin>jar xf C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2\glassfish-4.1.zip
ECHO.
ECHO Press any key to exit. 
pause>null
```

the log indicated that the icalcs was successful but when the extraction starts i got an ' access denied' message

**---- EDIT ----**

i've tried to make sure that i have all permission granted on the zip file to extract so i added

```
icacls C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2\* /grant "Tout le monde":f
```

after the first icacls  but the extraction still didn't work

Comment: i converted the batch file into an .exe file so a system popup is shown for the user to confirm actions which gonna happen but still extraction fails

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin>jar` why is the `>` ?

Comment: i found it somewhere like that with the >. Now i changed it to \ but extraction still not working

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052460/error-while-trying-to-extract-jar-file/18052502#18052502 i found someone saying that permissions aren't granted to the user on the folder containing the jar.exe. Maybe it is the default location for the extracted files, i will look how to personalize the extraction location

Comment: i tried with this command : call C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2>jar xf glassfish-4.1.zip  but it doesn't work too

Comment: well, right now i still have problems with my java home variable. i ll install evevrything again and try that same command later. Thanx

Comment: i checked that java_home and the path are set but still it didn't work

Comment: you need to set `%java_home%\bin` to the path....

Comment: i did but it's not the problem. i'm sure it's about permissions.

Comment: Just try to call the `jar` executable without the file parameter to see if you have the permissions to call it.

Comment: i have permissions to call it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to say that I think your script looks a little bit weired.

In the first line

```
call xcopy glassfish-4.1.zip C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2
```

you are copying the zip file to a folder on the Desktop, this already requires write access rights in `C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2` or it won't work.

In the next line you try to set the access rights for this folder:

```
icacls C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2 /grant "Tout le monde":f
```

As described, this doesn't make much sense because you already have written the zip file to this folder, therefore you must have at least write access rights.

Now to the problem, the call:

```
call C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin>jar xf C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2\glassfish-4.1.zip
```

is something which shouldn't work anyway because there is a space between **Program** and **Files**. I don't know what this `bin>jar` should be but if this works for you, then you may use it in this way.

I would write it like this:

```
call "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\jar.exe" xf C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2\glassfish-4.1.zip
```

If this call gives you an `Access denied.` message then you probably don't have write access rights in the current path of the command line.

**Note that the `jar` utility will extract the content of the zip file to the current path of the command line. That means if you are in `c:\` then it will extract the content to `c:\` and if you are in `c:\bla\` then it will extract the content to `c:\bla\`.** (It doesn't make a difference if you call it with the full path or only `jar` when it is in your PATH var.)

So this looks like you don't have the right access rights in the path where your glassfish-4.1.zip is, because this is the current path of your command line. I guess you want to extract the content to the folder on the Desktop. To do this, just change the current path to this folder before issuing the extract call.

I guess the script could look like this:

```
call xcopy glassfish-4.1.zip C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2
cd C:\Users\Feki\Desktop\vvv2\
call "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\jar.exe" xf glassfish-4.1.zip
```

**See also:**

- [creating batch script to unzip a file without additional zip tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704041/creating-batch-script-to-unzip-a-file-without-additional-zip-tools)
- [Unjar to a specific destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970432/unjar-to-a-specific-destination)
- [Extracting .jar file with command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453543/extracting-jar-file-with-command-line)

Comment: jar only worked for me locally (in the current folder) and it never worked for any file placed in a remote folder. this is my first days working with the batch scriptinig and i forgot that it's like in dos where i can use CD... so Thanks ALOT man!!